# DCCP Socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, dccp

I have tried to create socket in c for DCCP protocol,it complies with out error but when I run the program I get error  "sendto: Broken pipe"

I have include the necesseray header definition.

`#define SOCK_DCCP 6 
 #define IPPROTO_DCCP 33
 #define SOL_DCCP 269`

and in the function where I wanted to create a socket

```
int dccp_sockfd,port_num,addr_len,yes = 1;

struct sockaddr_in PMU_addr,their_addr;

struct Lower_Layer_Details *temp_pmu = (struct Lower_Layer_Details *) temp;
```

`unsigned char *dccp_BUF,*ptr,length[2];`

```
unsigned int flen;

uint16_t cal_crc,frame_crc;

port_num = temp_pmu->port;

struct Lower_Layer_Details *t ;


if ((dccp_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DCCP, IPPROTO_DCCP)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}

if (setsockopt(dccp_sockfd,SOL_DCCP,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(1);
```

`dccp_BUF = malloc(MAXBUFLEN* sizeof(unsigned char));`

```
addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr); 
int n,bytes_read;
unsigned char *cmdframe = malloc(19);
cmdframe[18] = '\0';
create_command_frame(1,temp_pmu->pmuid,(char *)cmdframe);


if ((n = sendto(dccp_sockfd,cmdframe, 18, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&PMU_addr,sizeof(PMU_addr)) == -1)) {

    perror("sendto"); 

} else {
```

Comment: Is `IPPROTO_DCCP` or the other macros defined by you? Plus, you should  show the code around `sendto`

Comment: IPPROTO_DCCP and the other macros are defined by the protocol and I have included above the sendto part of the code

Comment: Somebody with 1.5k rep could maybe add the DCCP tag to this question, even though its pretty generic.

Answer (score 3):

Do you call `connect()` or `bind()`and `listen()`? The current code snippets dont show those. In case those are missing, try adding them. To enable us to help you better, please make the question [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

In case your platform is Linux, please read http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/dccp especially the section "C Application Programming Interface to DCCP".

Comment: yes, I missed calling the connect(), that was the problem. I really appreciate the help